# cvc-pattern-valid: Value is not facet-valid with respect to pattern

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

Here is the entire error:

```
cvc-pattern-valid: Value '03151364512' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '((((\+011)|(011))[-]?)?(599)((416)|(717)|(318))[0-9]{4})|(((085)|(088))[-]?[0-9]{7})([,][1-9][0-9]{1,8})?|((((\+31)|(0)|(0031))[1-9][0-9]{2})[-]?([1-9][0-9]{5}))([,][1-9][0-9]{1,8})?|((((\+31)|(0)|(0031))[1-9][0-9])[-]?([1-9][0-9]{6}))([,][1-9][0-9]{1,8})?|(((14)[-]?)(0)([1-9][0-9]{1,2}))|((((\+31)|(0)|(0031))6){1}[-]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7})|\+(1\d{4,14}|2[078]\d{3,13}|3[0-469]\d{3,13}|4[013-9]\d{3,13}|5[1-9]\d{3,13}|6[0-6]\d{3,13}|7\d{4,14}|8[1-469]\d{3,13}|9[0-58]\d{3,13}|[2-9]\d{4,14})'
```

Every online checker I've used says this value should be valid. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, the value you test against is not matched with the regex *fully*. XSD regex requires a full string match. See [your "lean" regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ytkbdv/1), it does not match the last `2` in your input. So, it is invalid. What are your pattern requirements?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, you are correct. The problem I'm having is that our front-end validator (Angular in this case), with the same pattern, is allowing this value through, but then it doesn't pass the XSD validation.

Comment: Ok, that is the background. What are the actual requirements? It is impossible to help  you solve the issue without understanding what values must be valid and which not. What is faulty is not clear: the Angular validation or XSD?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I believe the pattern is actually correct then and it's Angular that is incorrectly allowing this value through. That's where I need to fix the problem.

Comment: Ok, the pattern should look like `/^(?:(\+?011-?)?599(416|717|318)[0-9]{4}|08[58]-?[0-9]{7}(,[1-9][0-9]{1,8})?|(\+31|0|0031)[1-9][0-9]{2}-?[1-9][0-9]{5}(,[1-9][0-9]{1,8})?|(\+31|0|0031)[1-9][0-9]-?[1-9][0-9]{6}(,[1-9][0-9]{1,8})?|14-?0[1-9][0-9]{1,2}|(\+31|0|0031)6-?[1-9][0-9]{7}|\+(1\d{4,14}|2[078]\d{3,13}|3[0-469]\d{3,13}|4[013-9]\d{3,13}|5[1-9]\d{3,13}|6[0-6]\d{3,13}|7\d{4,14}|8[1-469]\d{3,13}|9[0-58]\d{3,13}|[2-9]\d{4,14}))$/` in Angular. If it does not work, please add the Angular code to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much, that worked (without the forward slashes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD patterns [should match](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) the entire string.

So, the pattern does not match `03151364512` as expected since the last `2` [is not matched](https://regex101.com/r/ytkbdv/1).

You should fix the Angular validation to disallow partial string matches using

```
/^(?:(?:\+?011-?)?599(?:416|717|318)[0-9]{4}|08[58]-?[0-9]{7}(?:,[1-9][0-9]{1,8})?|(?:\+31|0|0031)[1-9][0-9]{2}-?[1-9][0-9]{5}(?:,[1-9][0-9]{1,8})?|(?:\+31|0|0031)[1-9][0-9]-?[1-9][0-9]{6}(?:,[1-9][0-9]{1,8})?|14-?0[1-9][0-9]{1,2}|(?:\+31|0|0031)6-?[1-9][0-9]{7}|\+(?:1\d{4,14}|2[078]\d{3,13}|3[0-469]\d{3,13}|4[013-9]\d{3,13}|5[1-9]\d{3,13}|6[0-6]\d{3,13}|7\d{4,14}|8[1-469]\d{3,13}|9[0-58]\d{3,13}|[2-9]\d{4,14}))$/
```

Note the regex literal notation, it should not be enclosed with any quotation marks.

Actually, in JavaScript, you may use non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`) rather than capturing ones (`(...)`), to save some tiny bit of compuational resources.